# Analyzing Data Transfer cost by instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I have recently seen a rise in my AWS bills.
Specifically, a rise in Data Transfer costs under "Bandwidth".

The bill includes several ec2 instances. I am interested in finding out which instance is leading to a rise in the costs.

I go to the cost explorer, select the dates I want and select a Usage Type Group of "EC2 DATA TRANSFER - INTERNET (OUT)".
This accurately shows the recent spike in Data Transfer costs but it is always marked on the graph as "no instance type". Ie. I can't figure out which instance to associate the rise to.

How can I determine which instance is causing the rise in Data Transfer costs?

Thank you.

Comment: On the billing console you can enable detailed billing that pushes csv files to s3. You can also pick tags to help split out that usage further.  That may help narrow down the culprit